# SQL: Join two tables on multiple columns

Tags: sql

I'm trying to left join two tables (Table1 left join Table 2).

I want the tables to join on multiple columns. The attached picture shows the structure. All entries in Table1 with "Agency = 'External Agency 1'" should be joined with the respective entry in Table2. All others should be joined with the entry in Table2 where "Agency = ''".

The first part of the Join is easy but I don't get how I can have all entries that do not have a direct match on the field "Agency" match with the empty one.

[image]

Any hints would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should try doing something like this:

select .... from Table1 left join Table2 on 
(
Table1.Column1 = Table2.Column1 and 
Table1.Colimn2 = Table2.Column2 and 
...

)
This assumes that you have same column names in both tables

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work with:

```
FROM
    table1 t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
        ON t1.agency = 'External Agency 1' AND t2.agency = 'External Agency 1'
        OR t1.agency <> 'External Agency 1' AND t2.agency = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two left joins:

```
select t1.*,
       coalesce(t2.col, t2d.col) as col
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.agency = t2.agency left join
     table2 t2d
     on t2.agency is null;
```

What the first `join` is doing the match when the values are the same.  The second brings in a default value.  The default value is used when the first `join` has no match.